# Move value of a certain cell to the next open cell in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set up a database-like document that would allow for the user to be able to input a value into a cell, say C4, and have whatever value is put in cell C4 to be moved to the next free cell in column A.

Is there a function (or set of functions) I could use, or should I use VBA for excel to try to do this?

I'm kind of new to excel, so if anyone could guide me in the right direction that would be awesome. Thanks :)

Comment: maybe the Data Entry Form https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6cc7lUDLrXE

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Place this in the relevant `Worksheet` module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rTarget As Range

    Set rTarget = Me.Cells(4, 3)
    If Not Application.Intersect(rTarget, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = rTarget.Value
        rTarget.ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straight forward if you are only tracking a single cell.

Paste this inside the Worksheet's code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$C$4" Then
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Target.Value
        Target.Clear
    End If

End Sub
```